# Using react-i18next with React standalone component - 'missingKey' error

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

I am getting 'missingKey' error messages from i18next even though the translations appear to be loading (can see console logging). What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my i18n.js file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import i18nhttp from 'i18next-http-backend'
import Backend from 'i18next-chained-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

const options = {
  backends: [
    i18nhttp
  ],
    
  backendOptions: [
    { loadPath: '/api/constants/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.lang.json' }
  ]
}

i18n.use(Backend).use(LanguageDetector).use(initReactI18next).init({
  backend: options,
  ns: ['fin'],
  defaultNS: 'fin',
  fallbackNS: 'fin',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  keySeparator: false,
  debug: true,
  detection: {
    order: ['queryString', 'cookie'],
    cache: ['cookie'],
    lookupCookie:'website#lang',
  },
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false
  },
  react: {
    useSuspense: true
  }
}, (err, t) => {
  if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err);
  t('pinDescription') 
})

export default i18n
```

And here is my React component file:

```
import React, { Suspense }  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../../../scripts/i18n'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

  const Translation = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()
  
    return (
      <div className="translation-sample">
        <h2>Translation Sample - from files</h2>
        <p>{t('accountNumberDescription')}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const domElement = document.getElementById('translation-sample')

  if (domElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading ... </div>}>
          <Translation />
        </Suspense>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      domElement
    );
  }
```

For the translation that I'm trying to render in the init callback (t('pinDescription')) I'm getting this error:

```
i18next::translator: key "pinDescription" for languages "en" won't get resolved as namespace "fin" was not yet loaded This means something IS WRONG in your setup. You access the t function before i18next.init / i18next.loadNamespace / i18next.changeLanguage was done. Wait for the callback or Promise to resolve before accessing it!!!
```

Which is strange since the react-i81n docs indicates that this callback runs after the translations have loaded.

For this and for the key I'm trying to render in the component I also get 'missing Key' error:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en fin pinDescription pinDescription
i18next::translator: missingKey en fin accountDescription accountDescription
```

I have tried several things including:

1. Wrapping the init call in a promise, exporting that function and awaiting it in the component
2. Using the HOC method
3. Exporting the i18n instance from the i18n.js file and then importing it in the component and calling init (tried both awaiting and promise / then)

Additionally, if I use a Suspense wrapper component I see that the translations have loaded in the console (however I still get missing key errors). When I remove 'Suspense' and opt out of it in the i81n.js config, then I never see any indication in the console that the translations have loaded.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. What is the best way to await the init / translation loading process before using 't' in the component?

The main difference between what I am doing and what most of the examples in the documentation show is that they show i18n.js being loaded in the index.js file of a React application. I don't have any index.js file or React application - I am working with a single React component that will later be injected into an existing non-React application.

Additionally, there are no network errors, I can access the language json files directly in the browser without a problem and I can see the translations loading in the console.

Output from the browser console (I'm using a different namespace here, but the code is the same):

[image]

Thanks in advance for any tips or for pointing out where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `i18next provider`

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import i18n from '../../../scripts/i18n';
import { useTranslation, I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

const Translation = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className="translation-sample">
      <h2>Translation Sample - from files</h2>
      <p>{t('accountNumberDescription')}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const domElement = document.getElementById('translation-sample');

if (domElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> // <----
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading ... </div>}>
          <Translation />
        </Suspense>
      </I18nextProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    domElement
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the provider is needed? I didn't see any mention of it here: https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks
https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start

Comment: I'm sure, you can see in the source code of `useTranslation` that it uses `useContext`
https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/src/useTranslation.js#L8

Comment: ah, good observation. however it does look like using the provider is optional. i was getting the 'i18n' instance from the 'useTranslation()' hook but had omitted it from my code posted above (I had removed it while experimenting). added it back to the code snippet above.

Comment: Did you tried to add the provider? look at the code, it doing much more then using the context

Comment: In addition, why do you use `i18next-chained-backend` there is no need for it, just use the http one

Comment: I just tried it with the Provider and unfortunately still getting the same errors. Yes, looks like 'i18next-chained-backend' is not necessary (I inherited this code) so I removed that too. 

To me, the fact that the translation in the init callback is not working is a clue that the problem lies somewhere in the i81n.js setup. This is before the React component even comes into play. I would expect the translations to have loaded by the time the callback code executes. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: No network errors. In fact I can see the translations loading despite the errors. I just added a screenshot of the console above (click to see details).

Comment: Will you be able to create a small repo that recreates the issue?

Comment: Sure, I will have to distill it down into a simpler form from the actual full app that I am working on - I will do that if I can't solve this by end of day today - thanks.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that I had another i18n instance running from another component that was conflicting with the one above. Once I removed that everything started working fine. 

The only thing is, since this is a component library and not an application I don't have a single place where I can import i18n.js - I have to import it in every component individually.  I guess the proper solution would be to import i18n.js once, in the client app, however the client app does not have React. Lots of limitations specific to my project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: regarding the documentation for the hooks it should work like that: https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks
I have also problems using translation for multiple components and its sadly nowhere documented :(